# Parsing name-value pairs with quoted values in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I need to parse strings of name-value pairs. The values can be quoted strings, presumably so that their values can contain separator characters. Example:

```
Path="/5E13F93E/5E142BAA" Ref="U4"  Part="1"
```

Funkier example:

```
Path="/5E13F93E= 5E14 2BAA" Ref="U4"  Part="1"
```

Is there a standard way to do this in Python? I can't imagine writing my own character-level parser for this in 2020, but I can't immediately find anything in the standard library that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is supposed to be a series of POSIX variable assignments, you can use the `shlex` module:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> list(shlex.shlex('Path="/5E13F93E= 5E14 2BAA" Ref="U4"  Part="1"'))
['Path', '=', '"/5E13F93E= 5E14 2BAA"', 'Ref', '=', '"U4"', 'Part', '=', '"1"']
```

You'll have to remove the outer quotes from the values yourself, but that can get a little tricky. Leading quotes are easy to identify: if the first character of a value is `"` or `'`, remove it. However, if the *last* value is a quote, you need to check if it is escaped first (e.g., `foo=bar\"`

Comment: This is actually part of a file syntax, don't ask. Every line has a different micro-syntax to it. Most lines look like something that's designed for scanf(3) to read, but this one's different.

Comment: Then you may need to write your own parser. Just because something looks simple doesn't mean a pre-existing parser exists.